# Upgrade Cassandra Version Brisk

Tags: cassandra, brisk

How can I upgrade the cassandra version and thrift version in Brisk?

Is there any tutorials kind of stuffs avalailble? I changed the build.properties file but on build, the version I mentioned couldn't be located at any repository.

Im trying to upgrade because of [Cassandra Insertion Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612394/cassandra-insertion-error)
this issue im facing. I hope the comment mentioned there helps

What is the latest version of cassandra that brisk supports?

In support forums I see people mentioning, replace the jars. I don't understand where should I do that.

Thanks for Help in advance

Regards,
Tamil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to upgrade Brisk's cassandra version. 
I Downloaded apache-cassandra-0.8.6-bin from apache site. 
Copied

lib/apache-cassandra-0.8.6.jar and lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-0.8.6.jar

to

brisk-1.0~beta2-bin/resources/cassandra/lib/

and removed the older version's cassandra and thrift jars

and just restarted brisk with ./brisk cassandra

and tried this

```
 $ ./nodetool -h x.x.x.x version

    ReleaseVersion: 0.8.6
```

So, I hope there won't any compatability issues, since in a forum a brisk dev mentioned tat brisk core works independently against cassandra core. But I'm yet to know the way to do it by building from src rather replacing jars in bin

Regards,
Tamil