# upgrade cassandra in brisk community version

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, brisk

Anybody tried to upgrade cassandra version from 0.8.* to 1.0 in `Brisk-1.0-beta2`?

`Brisk-1.0-beta2` comes with cassandra 0.8.1.
Somebody already tried to upgrade cassandra 0.8.1 to 0.8.6. See this question:
[Upgrade Cassandra Version Brisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618589/upgrade-cassandra-version-brisk)

But anybody tried to upgrade cassandra version from 0.8.* to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Answered on DataStax support forum:

http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/brisk-cassandra-10